# @WebMvcTest with @Autowire Constructor in WebConfig

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, environment-variables

I want to test a Spring `RestController`. There is a Web Config in this project with an `@Autowired Constructor`, which should initialize a ConfigurationPropertie with environment variables from the `application-{environment}.yml`-file. Since I have implemented this, my Application runs correctly but the WebMvcTest for the Controller is failing with following error:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'webConfig': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.project.onlineDate.shared.entity.OriginAllowedUrisProperties' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
```

#### Code Part 1: EnvironmentPropertie Class

```
@Configuration
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "origins")
public class OriginAllowedUrisProperties {

    String[] allowedUris;

    //Getter and Setter
}
```

#### Code Part 2: WebConfig

```
@Configuration
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    private final
    OriginAllowedUrisProperties originAllowedUrisProperties;

    @Autowired
    public WebConfig(OriginAllowedUrisProperties originAllowedUrisProperties) {
        this.originAllowedUrisProperties = originAllowedUrisProperties;
    }

    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        registry.addMapping("/**")
                .allowedOrigins(
                        originAllowedUrisProperties.getAllowedUris());
    }

}
```

#### Code Part 3: WebMvcTest

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@WebMvcTest(OnlineDateController.class)
class TestOnlineDateController {

    [...]

    @MockBean
    private OnlineDateService onlineDateService;

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Test
    void testGetOnlineDate() throws Exception {

        when(onlineDateService.findOnlineDates().thenReturn(
                Collections.singletonList(new OnlineDate()));

        mockMvc.perform(
                get("/onlineDates")
                        .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
                .andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andExpect(JSON_ONLINE_DATE_MATCHER)
                .andDo(print());
    }
}
```

#### Attemps for fix

I tried for example to declare a Context Configuration at Class Level with `@ContextConfiguration(classes = {WebConfig.class})` and I´ve tried to exclude the configuration with `@Filter` declaration. I have also tried a lot with the OriginAllowedUrisProperties.class to load environment variables in another way, but nothing worked. What am I missing? Do you have an Idea? Thanks in advance.

Comment: WHat does your `@SpringBootApplication` annotated class look like?

Comment: The Class is annotated with `@SpringBootApplication`. As we have multiple variants to get the configuration variables, I decided to annotate the `OriginAllowedUrisProperties` Class with @Component, in order not to make the Main class too confusing. Reference: [Baeldung](https://www.baeldung.com/configuration-properties-in-spring-boot)

Comment: As you are using a sliced test only parts of the app will be loaded. You would need to provide a mock for the `OriginAllowedUrisProperties` as well. (Also it is weird that it is both an `@Component` and `@Configuration`.

Comment: I tried this. But when I mock the Class in the following way that when the `getAllowedUris()` Method is called, return a `String[]` I get a `NullPointerException`. Probably because the `WebConfig` (where the Method is used) needs the call before the WebMvcTest to create the Context. 
Thanks for your answer. You´re right in that last point. I removed the `@Component` annotation.

Comment: When creating the mock you will also need to register behaviour, else it will return `null` (the default behaviour).

Comment: I registered the behavior like the following: ```when(originAllowedUrisProperties.getAllowedUris()).thenReturn(new String[]{"string1", "sting2"});```

Comment: Problem is that the configuration is loaded quite early, so the behaviour registration, when done in a method or regular before will probably be too late.

Comment: That was also my assumption. Do you have any idea how to load environment variables for the config? In this case for the WebConfig. I would like to implement that way, because I want to set different Cors Mappings in various environments.

Comment: You could try `@WebMvcTest({OnlineDateController.class, OriginAllowedUrisProperties.class })`. Also as request could you please add your `@SpringBootApplication` annotated class.

Comment: That is it! Thank you very much, this works. In my opinion it is not the cleanest way, because I want to declare in my `@WebMvcTest` only the Controller that is tested, but nvm. When you have an Idea for a cleaner Way, i would appreciate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After struggling to this I want to share my Solution. Hopefully this will help others who face the same challenge.After many attempts I have now solved it a bit differently.

### My Solution:

I pulled the bean declaration out of the entity and made it directly in the web controller. This information is not needed anywhere else in the project and therefore I can leave all test classes as they are. Here are the code components, which I have changed in contrast to above.

#### Code Part 1: EnvironmentProperty Class

- Removed Spring Annotations

```
public class OriginAllowedUrisProperties {

    String[] allowedUris;

    //Getter and Setter
}
```

#### Code Part 2: WebConfig

- Bind the `@ConfigurationProperties` on a `@Bean` method in `WebConfig` to bind externalized properties to the `OriginAllowedUrisProperties`

```
@Configuration
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "origins")
    public OriginAllowedUrisProperties originAllowedUrisProperties() {
        return new OriginAllowedUrisProperties();
    }

    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        registry.addMapping("/**")
                .allowedOrigins(originAllowedUrisProperties().getAllowedUris());
    }

}
```